# marklogic pojo databinding without annotate

Tags: mapping, marklogic, pojo

Is it possible to define a mapping without using the annotate? Like mentioned below:

> @id or @PathIndexProperty(scalarType = ScalarType.STRING)

I want to define binding in external file and say to **newPojoRepository** to use it in order to do the mapping.

Thanks.

Pinna

Answer (score 1):

You can always create a new class which extends your independent pojo object and attach your pojo annotations to the new class.  Here's an example.  Remember to create your Path Range Index of type int on ManagedCat/averageHeight.

Cat.java

```
public class Cat {
    private String id;
    private int averageHeight;

    public Cat() {}

    public Cat(String id, int averageHeight) {
        this.id = id;
        this.averageHeight = averageHeight;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getAverageHeight() {
        return averageHeight;
    }

    public void setAverageHeight(int averageHeight) {
        this.averageHeight = averageHeight;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "id=[" + id + "] averageHeight=[" + averageHeight + "]";
    }
}
```

ManagedCat.java

```
import com.marklogic.client.pojo.annotation.Id;
import com.marklogic.client.pojo.annotation.PathIndexProperty;
import com.marklogic.client.pojo.annotation.PathIndexProperty.ScalarType;

public class ManagedCat extends Cat {
    public ManagedCat() {
        super();
    }

    public ManagedCat(String id, int averageHeight) {
        super(id, averageHeight);
    }

    @Id
    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return super.getId();
    }

    @PathIndexProperty(scalarType = ScalarType.STRING)
    @Override
    public int getAverageHeight() {
        return super.getAverageHeight();
    }
}
```

CatManager.java

```
import com.marklogic.client.DatabaseClient;
import com.marklogic.client.DatabaseClientFactory;
import static com.marklogic.client.DatabaseClientFactory.Authentication.DIGEST;
import com.marklogic.client.pojo.PojoPage;
import com.marklogic.client.pojo.PojoQueryDefinition;
import com.marklogic.client.pojo.PojoRepository;
import static com.marklogic.client.pojo.PojoQueryBuilder.Operator.GT;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CatManager {
    private DatabaseClient client = DatabaseClientFactory.newClient(
        "localhost", 8000, "admin", "admin", DIGEST);
    private PojoRepository<ManagedCat, String> catRepo =
        client.newPojoRepository(ManagedCat.class, String.class);
    private PojoQueryDefinition largeCatQuery =
        catRepo.getQueryBuilder().range("averageHeight", GT, 20);
    private long start = 1;

    public void saveCat(ManagedCat cat) {
        catRepo.write(cat);
    }

    public Cat getCat(String id) {
        return catRepo.read(id);
    }

    public List<Cat> getLargeCats() {
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList<Cat>();
        catRepo.search(largeCatQuery, start)
            .forEach(cat -> list.add(cat));
        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CatManager catMgr = new CatManager();
        catMgr.saveCat( new ManagedCat("houseCat", 10) );
        catMgr.saveCat( new ManagedCat("lion",     45) );

        System.out.println("saved house cat=[" + catMgr.getCat("houseCat")+ "]");
        System.out.println("saved lion=[" + catMgr.getCat("lion")+ "]");
        System.out.println("large cats=[" + catMgr.getLargeCats()  + "]");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java this is such a common issue that there exist many data mapping tools available which give you a wide range of choices.
To start with, most data mapping tools happily ignore annotations that they dont handle specifically.  A common use case is mapping JAXB classes to other uses (which are full  of annotations). 
The Jackson DataBinding library (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind) , for example, will work perfectly fine on classes with 'foreign' annotations.   I would first check with your tools to verify you need to do anything at all.

Much more common case is when a data mapping tool requires its own annotations but you want to map 3rd party classes for which you don't have source or cant change.   Again, Jackson handles this well with many options including a "View" and "Mixin"

For data binding libraries that are not connect to serialization and also designed for this same problem consider pure "Data Mapping" libraries
which will map/copy one class to another without customizing either class.

MapStruct: http://mapstruct.org/
Dozer: https://github.com/DozerMapper/dozer

Note that Jackson's DataMapper works both with data binding and data mappping.

Here's a list with many - I havent tried most of these,
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/java-object-to-object-mapper.html